# Pure CSS change styling of div element with checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to toggle the CSS of a sibling  by using the checked state of a sibling checkbox.

Is it possible to target elements anywhere on the page from the checked pseudo class from a  checkbox?

I'm trying to avoid using any javascript.

https://codepen.io/dyk3r5/pen/WOmxpV?editors=1111

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 5px 1px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked > div p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="new-account">
    <input type="radio" id="opt1" name="radiolist" checked>
    <label for='opt1'>New Account</label>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="existing-account">
    <input type="radio" id="opt2" name="radiolist">
    <label for='opt2'>Existing Account</label>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ha ha! Its there! ;-) Im a back end dev, as you can propbably imagine. Is it even possible to target a div like this by its id?

Comment: Your question says "toggle the CSS of a sibling" and then it says "target elements anywhere on the page". Which are you interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked > div p
```

your `div` element is not a "direct children" of `input` element. What you need here is "general sibling selector" to address any following `div` sibling.

So it should be:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div p
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css like

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .content p {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Instead of hard-wiring the dependency on the intermediate `label` element, you'd be better off using the general sibling combinator `~`.